# Find this quote regarding Inspiration of the Apocrapha

Tags: reference-request, inspiration

I once read a passage from one of the apocrypha books but I don't remember which one. I believe that it's from one of the books of the Maccabees but I was unable to find it. In paraphrasing, from what i remember, the passage goes as follow:

"I do not know if all that I wrote was true and correct but I wrote to the best of my ability."

Can anyone help me find this quote or one that is similar? Thanks!

Comment: No such passage exists claiming they aren't sure if everything is *true,* only comments about their personal ability to write well, which is unrelated. Even St. Paul talks about his non-eloquency. 'Apocrypha' has nothing to do with it really. 2 Macc. 15 says: "Which if I have done well, and as it becometh the history, it is what I desired: but if not so perfectly, it must be pardoned me. For as it is hurtful to drink always wine, or always water, but pleasant to use sometimes the one, and sometimes the other: so if the speech be always nicely framed,.. " etc. not the veracity of the words.

Comment: @SolaGratia The OP is not sure which book he is truly referring to.

Comment: @KenGraham Yes, I'm saving him time by telling him such a book does not exist in the 'Apocrypha;' he's thinking of passages which speak of the felt inadequacy of the writer themselves, which doesn't pertain to how true, or, as he says, "inspired" the work is.

Comment: The translation prologue to Sirach, for example, isn't even part of the Book, which he may also have in mind (i.e. "come with benevolence, and to read with attention, and to pardon us for those things wherein we may seem, while we follow the image of wisdom, to come short in the composition of words; for the Hebrew words have not the same force in them when translated into another tongue...") which is about the translator of the Greek translation, and not the author of Sirach.

Comment: Verse search questions are off topic here.